# Updating Document in MongoDB without Alphabetically order

Tags: mongodb

I am making one project on MongoDB and inserted some documents and now i am updating the documents by this code..

```
bson_init( query );

bson_append_string(query, "First", "A");
bson_append_string(query, "Second", "B");
bson_append_string(query, "Third", "C");
bson_append_string(query, "Fourth", "D");
bson_append_string(query, "Fifth", "E");

bson_finish(query );


bson_init( b );
bson_append_start_object(b,"$set");

if(checkBox_First->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "First", "Z");

if(checkBox_Second->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Second", "X");

if(checkBox_Third->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Third", "R");

if(checkBox_Fourth->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Fourth", "Y");

if(checkBox_Fifth->isChecked() == true)
bson_append_string( b, "Fifth","P");

bson_append_finish_object( b );

bson_finish(b );

mongo_update(conn,TEST_NS,query,b,MONGO_UPDATE_BASIC,0);
bson_destroy(query);
bson_destroy(b);
```

The code is working perfectly but after updating, the document is stored in Alphabetical order. Can anyone tell me how i can update document without sorting alphabetically. I am using `"$set"` Update parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you were experiencing here was [SERVER-2592: fields in a document are reordered (sorted alphabetically) when setting a field value](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592).

As of the MongoDB 2.6 production release, the existing order of fields is now maintained on updates.